# Autohotkey TextTrim (feat. Artist) from Song

Tags: autohotkey, texttrimming

I'm currently using an AutoHotkey script (that I didn't make) that picks up Song - Artist from my browser title and places that into a .txt file. I want to be able to remove (feat. XYZ Artist) from what the script picks up. Is there any way to do this? IE. turning this:

See You Again (feat. Charlie Puth) - Wiz Khalifa

into this:

See You Again - Wiz Khalifa

Or if I can take it even further to remove anything surrounded by parenthesis... IE. turning this:

Earned It (Fifty Shades of Grey) (From The "Fifty Shades of Grey" Soundtrack) - The Weekend

into this:

Earned It - The Weekend

Can anyone help me accomplish either of these?

Comment: Can you show your code, and/or what you have tried so far?

Comment: Sure, run a replacement with this regex: `\([^)]*\)`. Here's a manual: https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/RegExReplace.htm

Comment: This is the script I'm using https://github.com/gustafsonk/SFMT/blob/master/SFMT.ahk

Answer (score 1):

```
str := "See You Again (feat. Charlie Puth) - Wiz Khalifa"
str := RegExReplace(str, "\([^)]*\)", "")
```

You may need to adjust the RegEx to match other formats, too.